# Why is didReceiveData function not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, nsurlconnection

I have a class which is used to get data from my server. The data returned from my server is in JSON. For some reason the didReceiveData won't run at all. I have placed NSLogs inside it to test it but it doesn't do anything?

Here is my code:

```
+(NSJSONSerialization *) getTask:(id)task_id{

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&task_id=%@", task_id];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://my-server.com/"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(conn){
        NSLog(@"Testing");
    }

    return json;
}

// Log the response for debugging
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {
    NSLog(@"test");
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
}

// Declare any connection errors
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: Note that you *cannot*  return the received JSON from the `getTask:` method, because NSURLConnection works *asynchronously*. - Perhaps you cancel the connection after returning from `getTask:` ?

Comment: I am not sure. How can I place the NSURLConnection in a class then?

Comment: Because the above code is going to be used nultiple times throughout my app, which is why I placed it in a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getTask:` is a class method, which means the `self` is the class. Therefore the delegate methods must also be class methods.

But note that you cannot return the received JSON from the `getTask:` method, because `NSURLConnection` works asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks, that got the other methods working. Now I just need to figure how to return the json variable for my UIViewController that calls that class initially.

Comment: @PeterStuart: You cannot make an asynchronous method synchronous without blocking the current thread. - The usual method is that `connectionDidFinishLoading` calls back into the view controller with the received data. Note also that `didReceiveData:` may be called multiple times with chunks of data.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean? Do you have any documentation on this which can help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the connection. Try using the `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` method:

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

or, just call the start method:

```
if(conn){
    [conn start];
}
```

Comment: I do not think that explains it. According to the documentation, `initWithRequest:delegate:` is   equivalent to calling `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` and passing `YES` for `startImmediately`.

Comment: I have this code used elsewhere and it starts it automatically, but this is the first time I am using it in a class so that may be why. I'll report back. Thanks